# Android studio parsing json object

Tags: java, android, json

i have a issue with my code in android studio. the url of json object is not been open. when i change the url for testing whether there is any problem with my code or not, it is ok. and the only diffrence between those two urls is one of them is https (which run without any problem) and the other is http (which is not working). how can i run the code with out problem?

```
package com.example.chatbot;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void onClick(View view){
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String input = textView.getText().toString();
        //textView.setText(" ");

        TextView out=findViewById(R.id.outPut);

        
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        String url ="http://api.brainshop.ai/get?bid=159114&key=OCfIpglFJbfXDt2G&uid=[uid]&msg=[msg]=hello";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //set the text
                String res = response.toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                out.setText(res);
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        queue.add(request);
    }


}
```

Comment: You should put something in your `onErrorResponse` so you know if you get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set "android:usesCleartextTraffic" flag to true in your AndroidManifest file.
Since target api 28 it defaults to false.  [more info here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)